# append character to a two dimensional array value in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

```
 char str1[50][50];
 char str2[40]="1";
 char str3[40];
 for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
      printf("enter the value\n");
      scanf("%c",&str1[0][i]);   //entered values in zeroth row only                   
    }
  strcat(str1[0][2],str2);
```

my requirement is just to show the concatenated text i.e 
**if the user input
str1[0][2]=a
then the output should be a1**

error:
 **invalid conversion from `char' to`char*'**

Answer (score 1):

The `scanf` "%s" format specifier is for a string and `str1[0][i]` is a character. You can't read a string into a variable that holds a single character.

Comment: i have replaced it by %c still d same problem

Comment: Right, but since it's the exact same problem, it has the exact same solution. And you already know what the solution is because I told you. `strcat(str1[0][2],str2);` What is `str1[0][2]`? And read the documentation for `strcat` -- it concatenates **two strings**.